# How can I remove specific ticks and rearrange the chart? Please the attached image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am new to ChartJS and trying to tweak the chart. I have removed specific y-axis ticks using callback function but getting space between the remaining ticks but I want to rearrange the chart with same width between ticks.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJmTF.png)

Here is the sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5sp1e9t/) which I tried.

Can someone help me?

```js
var data = [{
  x: 0,
  y: 10
}, {
  x: 2,
  y: 10
}, {
  x: 6,
  y: 10
}, {
  x: 10,
  y: 50
}];

var labels_x = [1.6666666666666665, 9.666666666666666, 17.666666666666668, 25.666666666666668, 33.666666666666664, 41.666666666666664, 49.666666666666664, 57.666666666666664] // note computed values not integer
var labels = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon']

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: data
    }, ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          callback(value, index) {
            if (value != 20 && value != 25) {
              return value;
            }
            console.log("val::::::::", value)
          }
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 61,
          autoSkip: false,
          callback(value, index) {
            return labels[index];
          }
        },
        afterBuildTicks(scale) {
          return labels_x;
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What output do you expect? If the chart was to collapse to remove the tick locations it would be distorted and somewhat deceptive. What problem are you trying to solve by removing them?

Comment: @isherwood, I want to remove the space between 15&30 ticks in y-axis.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. You haven't answered the questions I actually asked. _What should happen with the graph?_

Comment: Graph will be same and the remaining labels will be equally separated/rearrange.

Comment: The lines won't connect. It _can't_ be the same.

Comment: @isherwood I attached an image for the clear idea

Comment: Maybe you can set (and increase) the "ticks.stepSize" option in order to reduce the gap